# Twitter Bootstrap Responsive Layout breaks in Firefox

Tags: css, layout, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm creating a responsive layout using Twitter Bootstrap, but it appears to break in Firefox on the first page load, but then after a while without refreshing the page, it seems to work fine.

I even tried to strip the page down to a basic example like, and it still didn't work, here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Hello</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
        <h3>Main content</h3>
        <p>Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
        <p>Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <h4>Sidebar</h4>
        <p>Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

**The problem actually only appears to be on my machine. I've tested it on three others and it works fine. Perhaps there's a problem with my installation of Firefox? I'm using a Mac, OSX 10.6.8.
I'll update this question when I've tried reinstalling Firefox.**

Comment: What's your issue you are facing? A screenshot perhaps? And also the resolution please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try these things:

1. Upgrade the firefox version you are using.
2. Delete the cookies from your browser.
3. Install firebug and developers toolbar to inspect the page and the problem might be in the `.css`. Check against it, in the firebug by removing some properties.

Comment: Upgrading Firefox and deleting the cookies worked. But I should note that I FULLY uninstalled Firefox - including the user profile, which can be found with these instructions: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#How_to_find_your_profile

Answer (score 2):

I've had this happen to me as well, currently with Firefox 17.01 and Mac OSX 10.8.2

Responsive Bootstrap sites don't work correctly, the spans don't collapse as the screen narrows. Even the official Bootstrap site appears not to work correctly.

I think it may be caused by some Firefox extensions. Not sure which ones, but if I switch to a different user on this same machine, a user who has no FF extensions installed, the problem disappears.

Good luck!

Comment: Looking into this some more, I can confirm that on my system the problem was caused by the Mozbar 2.22 Firefox plugin. If I disable the plugin, Firefox starts displaying Bootstrap based sites correctly on narrow screens.  If you still want to use the Mozbar, there's also a Chrome version which seems to work OK if you pin the toolbar to the side of the screen.

Comment: For me it was the Grease Monkey plug-un that caused it not to work. After I removed it, the css worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
<div class="container">...</div>
```

Before the

```
<div class="row"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, I changed my code above to show the new version

Comment: Yea... What is the issue are you facing? Let us know that? Breaks means? Is there a screenshot?

Answer (score -2):

I got around this by creating a special CSS media query for only Firefox for the problem viewport width.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .span1 {
      width: 129.14px;
    }
}
}
```

**N.B.** I'm using a customised grid here where there are just 7 columns (.span1's) per row (.row). If you are using the standard 12 columns then the width will be different but you can use the same method to fix it.

Answer (score -3):

I found solution somewhere in internet...

```
table {table-layout:fixed}
```

It solve problems in Firefox & IE, with bootstrap 2 & 3